# Zest: How to change the connection line style?

Tags: eclipse, zest

I'm using GraphViewer of Zest. I've also used content and label provider for it. The line or connection doesn't contain a arrow in one of it's end. How to change the style of the line? I'm following this tutorial:   http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseZest/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use style for graphconnection.

new MyGraphConnection(graph, ZestStyles.CONNECTIONS_DIRECTED, source, destination)

Comment: Please add 4 spaces before the line of code to actually make it appear as code. Thanks. [reviewer]